# NUXT 2 - Universal SSR hosting options and howto

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, vuejs2, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

This is really frustrating.

I have built a website using Nuxt 2 in Universal SSR mode. It's all working locally on my machine which is fantastic! Now, I want to host/deploy it on a suitable hosting server for my client. Baring in mind that this is the first project I work on with Nodejs (since NUXT uses nodejs). I have just spent days trying to deploy this website with no success.

I have never been in a position like this where I did all the hard work building the website and having it run nicely on my machine, then to realise that I am not able to host it on a server! I cannot find any tutorial that is clear enough to guide me into hosting this already built website!

I am looking to host on AWS Lambda. Can anyone guide me? Is anyone interested in helping me for a small fee? This site needs to go live!!!

**UPDATE**

I ended up deploying to google app engine following a couple of tutorials online. The process is super easy. The app is running now online finally! But AWS Lambda is not easy at all and needs some server AWS experience to get it running. Not worth the headache for me. Another good option is Heroku. So I will be deciding between Google App Engine and Heroku since both are super easy to setup a Universal SSR Nuxt app and there is alot of articles explaining the easy process for both of them.

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

Google app engine was not suitable in the end. Too complex and not what we wanted to waist our time on. So we started using DigitalOcean. What a breeze and the docs/tutorials for setting up everything are second to none.

Comment: https://dev.to/adnanrahic/a-crash-course-on-serverless-side-rendering-with-vuejs-nuxtjs-and-aws-lambda-1nk4

Comment: for VPS deployment: https://gist.github.com/DreaMinder/e9fc988295378d8373521a93c3ca6d18

Comment: Thanks. I had a look at that tutorial "A crash course on serverless..." but I couldn't follow the instructions and also it's old (nuxt v1). Surely it shouldnt be this hard to just host an already built website?!?!

Comment: I don't know anything about AWS Lambda but if you can't follow Aldarund's link then maybe consider using a vps as DreaMinder suggests. Really detailed instructions for deploying to Digital Ocean can be found [here](https://kaloraat.com/articles/how-to-deploy-nuxtjs-ssr-app-to-digital-ocean). It might seem complex but if you just go step by step you should get it working. Digital Ocean has really good documentation so search that if you get stuck. Deploying a nuxt app is a lot more complex than a ftp of an index.html file so be prepared for that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Andrew. I ended up deploying to google app engine following a couple of tutorials online. The process is super easy. The app is running now thanks ;) But AWS Lambda is not easy at all and needs some server AWS experience to get it running. Not worth it for me. So I will be deciding between Google App Engine or Heroku since both are super easy to setup an Universal SSR Nuxt app and there is alot of articles explaining the easy process for both of them.

Comment: Hi @hga77, did you follow any article/tutorial to initiate yourself into the process? Thanks

Comment: Hi @Mattia, Yes I did. I probably read all articles relating to deploying Nuxt Universal to various hosting services. So far its working great on Google app engine. Here are the two articles.. It's super easy! https://nuxtjs.org/faq/appengine-deployment and https://medium.com/@pascalluther/deploying-a-nuxt-js-v2-app-to-google-app-engine-google-cloud-platform-69c9008531bc. Also this article talks about deploying to Azure and has useful info on how to skim down your css and js files, https://itnext.io/deploying-a-nuxt-universal-app-to-azure-f61e5a85d8a2

Comment: Google app engine ended up being a pain to work with so the project was finally deployed on DigitalOcean. Amazing hosting platform tbh.

Comment: i made an blog about how to deploy universal nuxt with an nginx reverse proxy and SSL cetrificate and domain name: https://blogxon.com/articles/how-to-deploy-nuxt-on-a-vps